# django prefetch_related filtered with object column

Tags: django, django-queryset

models:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    birth_date = models.DateField()

class PersonData(models.Model):
    (...)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    valid_from = models.DateField() #default data urodzenia (Person)
    valid_to = models.DateField(default=date(year=2999,month=12,day=31))
    
class Transaction(models.Model): 
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    (...)
```

And now I want to get transaction which are before context_date:

```py
context={}
context[context_date]=date.today()
    
transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(
    execution_date__lte=context['context_date']
).prefetch_related.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'person__persondata_set',
        queryset=PersonData.objects.filter(
            valid_to__gte=context['context_date'],
            valid_from__lte=context['context_date']
        )
    )
)
```

But this is inproper - because the prefetch data uses in global context_date.  I want to have name relevant to transaction.execution_date not context_date!

```py
Transaction.objects.filter(
    execution_date__lte=context['context_date']
).prefetch_related.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'person__persondata_set',
        queryset=PersonData.objects.filter(
            valid_to__gte=execution_date,
            valid_from__lte=execution_date
        )
    )
)
```

Which of course is wrong... I tried Q('execution_date'), F('execution_date') - but no luck